# Passing float to GLSL shader does nothing

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I've been having problems sending the shininess factor to my bump mapping shader.
The result always looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWt6C.jpg

But if I hard code the value inside the shader to 0.0 it's working just fine.
When I send 0.0 to the shader it's turning out like in the picture above.

Any ideas?

Here's my shader

```
#version 110

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D bmap;

uniform bool boolBump;
uniform vec4 vecColor;
uniform bool onlyColor;

uniform float fTransparencyThresh;
uniform float fShininess;
uniform float alpha;

varying vec3 vecLight;
varying vec3 vecEye;
varying vec3 vecNormal;

vec4 getLighting()
{
    //Ambient part
    vec4 color = (gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient) + (gl_LightSource[0].ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);

    //For bump mapping, the normal comes from the bump map texture lookup
    vec3 n = normalize(vecNormal);
    if(boolBump)
    {
         n = normalize(texture2D(bmap, gl_TexCoord[0].st).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0);
    }

    vec3 l = normalize(vecLight);

    //Lambert term
    float NdotL = dot(n, l);

    if(NdotL > 0.0)
    {
        //Diffuse part
        color += gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * max(0.0, NdotL);

        //Specular part
        vec3 e = normalize(vecEye);
        vec3 r = normalize(-reflect(l,n));  

        float spec = pow(max(0.0, dot(r, e)), fShininess);

        color += gl_LightSource[0].specular * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * spec;
    }

    return color;
}

void main(void)
{
    vec4 texel = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    if(texel.a < fTransparencyThresh)
        discard;

    //Get shading
        vec4 color = getLighting();

    //Color only mode?
    if(onlyColor)
    {
        color *= vecColor;
    }
    else
    {
        color *= texel;
    }   

    //Set fragment color, alpha comes from MTL file
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.xyz, alpha);
}
```

Edit, OpenGL code:

```
void MyClass::sendToShader(const OBJ::StelModel* pStelModel, Effect cur, bool& tangEnabled, int& tangLocation)
{
    int location;
    tangEnabled = false;

    if(cur != No)
    {
        location = curShader->uniformLocation("fTransparencyThresh");
        curShader->setUniform(location, fTransparencyThresh);

        location = curShader->uniformLocation("alpha");
        curShader->setUniform(location, pStelModel->pMaterial->alpha);

        location = curShader->uniformLocation("fShininess");
        curShader->setUniform(location, 0.0f);

...
```

Edit: Even this wont work:

```
GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(curShader->program, "fShininess");
glUniform1f(loc, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Please show opengl code as well.

Comment: edited it, sorry forgot about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that pow(0, 0) is undefined. This means `spec` is undefined if `dot(r, e) == 0` and `fShininess == 0`.

Comment: I guess this is the problem. I'll check it out later. Thanks

Comment: The thing is though, if I hardcode fShininess inside the shader to 0.0 it works fine.
If I send 0.0 into the shader -> black specks.

Comment: What if you set it to `0.0f` inside the shader? I dont know; between the UB and my lack of intricate knowledge, this is hard to speculate.

Comment: I assume you mean hardcode 0.0f?
e.g.: float power = pow(max(0.0, dot(r,e)), 0.0f))

I did this and it works fine, that's why I'm so confused about this

Comment: Yes. How about `0.0`? Or `double power`? In any case, I suggest you either use .00001 (i.e. an approximation of 0) or an if, to get around the 0^0 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you make sure the program is actively bound when you call glUniform? Do you check glGetError anywhere?

Comment: No I don't, but the other values seem to be fine. If i take the specular part away or set it to 0.0 the Illumination works fine. Wouldn't be the case if the program wasn't bound, right?

Comment: Please check both glGetError and the return value of glGetUniformLocation manually. It can save lots of debugging time to know for sure.

Comment: Error is always 0
Location is 3

this is with the GLint loc = ... code from above

Comment: This is really weird, if I send 0.0f in there I get all these black artifacts but if I send 0.1f in it seems fine.